# No provider for HttpService

Tags: angular, httpservice, angular2-providers

When I run the following project I get the error:

> No provider for HttpService! (AppComponent -> HttpService)

Can someone help me please?

my AppComponent:

```
    import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {HttpService} from "./htttp.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <div>
  <div class="input">
  <label for="title">Title</label>
  <input type="text" id="title" #title>
  </div>
    <div class="body">
  <label for="body">Body</label>
  <input type="text" id="body" #body>
  </div>
    <div class="user-id">
  <label for="user-id">User ID</label>
  <input type="text" id="user-id" #userid>
  </div>
  <button (click)="onPost(title.value, body.value, userid.value)">Post Data</button>
  <button (click)="onGetPosts()">Get All Posts</button>
  <p>Response: {{response | json}}</p>
  </div>,

  providers: [HttpService]
      `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  response: string;

  constructor(private _httpService: HttpService){}
  onGetPosts(){
    this._httpService.getPosts().subscribe(
      response => this.response=response,
      error => console.log(error)
    )
  }

}
```

HttpService:

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http} from "angular2/http";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()

export class HttpService{
  constructor(private _http:Http){}

  getPosts():Observable<any>{
    return this._http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').map(res => res.json());
  }

}
```

and boot.ts:

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {AppComponent} from "./app.component";
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from  "angular2/http";

bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS]);
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: You problem is here `import {HttpService} from "./htttp.service";` you have 3 `t` in `htttp` it should only 2

Comment: Thanks! what a silly mistake! :)

Comment: No worries. Now hit the `UP` button! Thanks!

Comment: I did. It doesn't work. I'll try again later

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be

```
import {HttpService} from "./http.service";
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close template literal 'back quote' before declaring your providers.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <div>
  <div class="input">
  <label for="title">Title</label>
  <input type="text" id="title" #title>
  </div>
    <div class="body">
  <label for="body">Body</label>
  <input type="text" id="body" #body>
  </div>
    <div class="user-id">
  <label for="user-id">User ID</label>
  <input type="text" id="user-id" #userid>
  </div>
  <button (click)="onPost(title.value, body.value, userid.value)">Post Data</button>
  <button (click)="onGetPosts()">Get All Posts</button>
  <p>Response: {{response | json}}</p>
  </div>`,
  providers: [HttpService]
})
```